# Can I Populate a Document Library's Calculated Value Column with Information Inside Documents?

Tags: document-library, metadata

I'm trying to drive SharePoint adoption over legacy tech like shared drives but running into what I suspect is a common problem. There are entrenched processes to fill in fields inside e.g. Word documents and nobody wants to enter the metadata for the document twice.

Knowing that there is e.g. a "Date This Agreement Comes Into Effect" or "Time of Incident" field in the document itself, can I automatically populate column values in a document library?

Comment: Not without reading/parsing the Word document with you own code, extracting what you need and then use SP code to update metadata. Maybe there is an App out there that can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use SharePoint build-in ability. When you create new Word document in the library, you can insert library column placeholder inside it. Column will be 2 side syncronized.

Typicaly it used as document template with inserted columns, but you can try use it your own way.

Here is the nice article https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/add-sharepoint-metadata-to-word-documents/

Comment: Thanks, but this is the exact opposite of what I'm trying to do.  This puts information from the Sharepoint column in the Word document, I'm trying to put information from the Word document in the Sharepoint column.  This incidentally solves another problem I have so thanks very much for the contribution!